# Generics can't make correct inferences

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

A generic class can require a matching generic object in it's constructor, like this [sscce](http://sscce.org):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericsIssue<K> {
  public List<K> inner; 

  public GenericsIssue(List<K> input) {
    if(input == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    this.inner = input;
  }

  public K getFirst() {
    if(inner.isEmpty()) return null;
    return inner.get(0);
  }
  // Snip, code continues below
```

Also, factory methods don't specify the generic type in it's arguments. For example, we might do this. Note, there aren't any warnings, not even "unchecked cast".

```
  // Code borrowed from Guava source
  public static <E> ArrayList<E> newArrayList() {
    return new ArrayList<E>();
  }
  // End Guava borrow      

  public static void main(String... args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = newArrayList();
    GenericsIssue<String> gi = new GenericsIssue<String>(list);
    System.out.println(gi.getFirst()); // (Always null. Not relevant.)
  }
}
```

However, this `main` is nearly the same thing, but it doesn't compile in JDK 7u25, either in Eclipse or at the command line. Why?

```
  public static void main(String... args) {
    GenericsIssue<String> gi = new GenericsIssue<String>(newArrayList());
    System.out.println(gi.getFirst());
  }
```

Here's the compiler error:

```
$ javac -d . -Xlint:unchecked GenericsIssue.java
GenericsIssue.java:23: error: constructor GenericsIssue in class GenericsIssue<K> cannot be applied to given types;
        GenericsIssue<String> gi = new GenericsIssue<String>(newArrayList());
                               ^
  required: List<String>
  found: ArrayList<Object>
  reason: actual argument ArrayList<Object> cannot be converted to List<String> by method invocation conversion
  where K is a type-variable:
    K extends Object declared in class GenericsIssue
1 error
```

Comment: You have labelled `[compile-errors]` but you haven't included any. What errors do you get? If you don't get any errors, how do you know it didn't compile? Which version of Java are you using, and is it a current update if you suspect a strange bug?

Comment: @PeterLawrey sorry, compiler error attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generics system is [limited in the inferences it can make](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html), and assignment is handled differently from method parameters. You should be able to specify

```
new GenericsIssue<String>(GenericsIssue.<String>newArrayList());
```

(Theoretically, that inference should be possible, but that level of analysis just isn't implemented yet.)

Comment: It's funny, just using the right word (in this case, inference) makes the answer findable. Hard to search, though, without using that exact word.

Comment: Worth knowing: The spec and the compiler is getting smarter in Java 8, so it will be able to infer the correct types in cases like the above. http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101

Comment: @gustafc I feel like every week I find another reason to be excited about Java 8 :)